# Flask: Function output not resolving as expected

Tags: python, flask

I am currently struggling to understand, why Python / Flask is resolving function outputs in weird ways.

In order to process input json data, I create a function that takes the input and adds an id and a created at field.

What I now expected to happen is that the id and timestamp fields created by the functions, contain the created values only, e.g. id = 7ae6613e-cddb-43b3-a5de-3336dab996fa.

Within the process it seems to be working.

But what actually gets returned:

```
Added item {'id': UUID('7ae6613e-cddb-43b3-a5de-3336dab996fa'), 'created_at': datetime.datetime(2021, 4, 25, 11, 29, 24, 328130), 'name': 'productB', 'brand': 'brandB'}
```

The function I use

```
@product.route("/product",methods=['POST'])
def create_product():
  if request.data:

    request_data = request.get_json()

    id = uuid.uuid4()
    timestamp = datetime.now()
    print(id)
    name = None
    brand = None

    if 'name' in request_data:
        name = request_data['name']   
   
    if 'brand' in request_data:
        brand = request_data['brand']
   
    _new_product = {
        "id": id,
        "created_at": timestamp,
        "name": name,
        "brand": brand
    }
    products.append(_new_product)
    return f"Added item {_new_product}", 200
```

Comment: `_new_product` is a dictionary. A formatted string of a dictionary always looks like that, why do you expect something else?

Comment: @MennoHölscher: Thanks for the response. I am not really sure, if I am missing something, or if you did. The formatted dict was not the problem, but the fact that I assumed that id and timestamp are passed as "string" values. Casting the values solved the problem. If you now a better way than casting, I am happy to hear it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem, by adding a str casting to id and timestamp.

Not sure if this is really the way to go, but it did fix it.

Happy to get feedback / a better solution. :)

For now, this solved it

```
 _new_product = {
        "id": str(id),
        "created_at": str(timestamp),
        "name": name,
        "brand": brand
    }
```